# How to make one array of object from two array of objects with one shared key - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I have to merge 2 array of object from rest api calls.
They are like: `[{date: date, name: name}, ...]`
Let's call them A array and B array.

If in the A arrays and B arrays have the same date, the final array-s object should like look this: `[{date: date, nameA: nameA, nameB: nameB}]`

If they dont, just insert insert and object like this: `[{date: dateA, nameA: nameA}]`

For example:

```
arrayA = [
    {
      date: 2017-01-01, 
      name: 'New Year Eve'}
    },
    {
      date: 2017-02-02, 
      name: 'feb2'
  }
]

arrayB = [
    {
      date: 2017-01-01, 
      name: 'New Year Eve'}
    },
    {
      date: 2017-03-03, 
      name: 'march3'
  }
]
```

The final array should look like this:

```
finalArray = [{
    date: 2017 - 01 - 01,
    nameA: 'New Year Eve',

    nameB: 'New Year Eve'
},
{
    date: 2017 - 02 - 02,
    nameA: 'feb2'
},
{
    date: 2017 - 03 - 03,
    nameB: 'march3'
}
```

]

And the objects with shared date can be in different position in the array, so i can't check simple like

```
arrayA[0].date === arrayB[0].date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the reference to the objects with the same date.

```js
var arrayA = [{ date: '2017-01-01', name: 'New Year Eve' }, { date: '2017-02-02', name: 'feb2' }],
    arrayB = [{ date: '2017-01-01', name: 'New Year Eve' }, { date: '2017-03-03', name: 'march3' }],
    merged = function merge(arrays, names) {
        var hash = Object.create(null),
            result = [];

        arrays.forEach(function (a, i) {
            a.forEach(function (b) {
                if (!hash[b.date]) {
                    hash[b.date] = { date: b.date };
                    result.push(hash[b.date]);
                }
                hash[b.date][names[i]] = b.name;
            });
        });
        return result;
    }([arrayA, arrayB], ['nameA', 'nameB']);

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var finalArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
        if (arrayA[i].date == arrayB[j].date) {

            //add to the final array if not exist that date
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more effective.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called `Array.prototype.concat()` and it is used to merge 2 arrays or more, in your example it is like this:

`finalArray = arrayA.concat(arrayB)`

And then you have to loop over the `finalArray`, delete any repeated date after taking its attributes and merge to the same date like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
                    if (finalArray[i]["date"] === finalArray[i+1]["date"] ) {
                        finalArray[i]["nameA"] = finalArray[i]["name"];
                        finalArray[i]["nameB"] = finalArray[i+1]["name"];
                        //delete the one that is repeated
                        delete finalArray[i+1][key]
                    }
        }
```

Hope that works

Comment: I think this solution is more dispendious but is elegant

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo thank you, this is how i think the solution could be, but i know there will be some bugs, it just needs some polishing.

Comment: Hm, thants a nice idea, thanks! But after the concat, the same dates not follow each other to be able to iterate over the finalArray like i and i + 1. For example after real requests and the concat, the '2016-03-28' date is in the finalArray[5] and at the finalArray[13]

Comment: yub I've noticed that too, unfortunately it is not working but I thought it would give you an idea about how it might works @aboutus

Answer (score 0):

You can use array from and subtract the length

```js
var arrayA = [{date: '2017-01-01', name: 'New Year Eve'},{date: '2017-02-02', name: 'feb2'}];var arrayB = [{date: '2017-01-01', name: 'New Year Eve'},{date: '2017-03-03',name: 'march3'}];

var arr= Array.from(new Array(arrayA.length+arrayB.length),(x,y)=> arrayB[y]||arrayA[y-arrayA.length] );
 console.log(arr);
```